# How to handle "Lost connection to device." error

Tags: flutter, authentication

I created an app, which contains login and dashboard screen, i used Nodejs backend and mongodb also. i trying to add functionality when user logged in and close the app without logging out and then when user come to the app it should display where it left last time. so i used shared preference for it. I am testing it now,  when i logged in and close the app using the  right-most button (which shows all the currently running apps) it send me this  **"Lost connection to device.
"**.

**login Code:**

```
bool newuser;
  String type ;
  SharedPreferences myPrefs;

void initState() {
    
    checkIfLoggedinalready();
    
  }

Future login() async {
    try {
      Dio dio = new Dio();
      var data = {
        'username':"Munib khatri",
        'password': "Munib123",
        'date': "5/5/2021"
      };
      await dio
          .post(localhostUrlLogin, data: json.encode(data))
          .then((onResponse) async {
         type = onResponse.data['User']['Type'];
        

        if (type == 'Employee') {
          Navigator.push(
              context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Employee()));
        } else if (type == 'Manager') {
          Navigator.push(
              context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Manager()));
        }
        myPrefs.setBool('login', false);
      });
    } catch (e) {
     
      
    }
  }


  void checkIfLoggedinalready() async{
   myPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    newuser = (myPrefs.getBool('login') ?? true);
    print(newuser);
    if (newuser == false && type == 'Employee') {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Employee()));
    }

  }
```

**dashboard code:**

i am doing this on drawer code where i use logout

```
 new ListTile(
              title: new Text('Log out'),
              leading: Icon(Icons.logout,color:Colors.grey),
              onTap: (){
                myPrefs.setBool('login', true); //here i set it to true, if user is new
                Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context)=>
                    
                    Login()
                    )
                  );
              },
            ),
```

please help it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var response =
    await http.post(Uri.parse(parseUse), body: json.encode(data), headers: {   "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8", }).timeout(Duration(minutes: 2));
```

**Updated Answer :**

```
   try{
    
   Dio dio = new Dio();
      var data = {
        'username':"Munib khatri",
        'password': "Munib123",
        'date': "5/5/2021"
      };
      await dio
          .post(localhostUrlLogin, data: json.encode(data))
          .then((onResponse) async {
         type = onResponse.data['User']['Type'];
        

        if (type == 'Employee') {
          Navigator.push(
              context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Employee()));
        } else if (type == 'Manager') {
          Navigator.push(
              context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Manager()));
        }
        myPrefs.setBool('login', false);
      });
    
    }on DioError catch (e){
    
    if(e.type == DioErrorType.connectTimeout){
    "You can put a alert dialog or something you prefer".
    }

    }
```

or you can also use base Option since your using DIO

```
var dio = Dio(); // with default Options

// Set default configs
dio.options.baseUrl = 'https://www.xx.com/api';
dio.options.connectTimeout = 5000; //5s
dio.options.receiveTimeout = 3000;

// or new Dio with a BaseOptions instance.
var options = BaseOptions(
  baseUrl: 'https://www.xx.com/api',
  connectTimeout: 5000,
  receiveTimeout: 3000,
);
Dio dio = Dio(options);

response = await dio.request(
  '/test',
  data: {'id':12,'name':'xx'},
  options: Options(method:'GET'),
);
```

Comment: could u please edit ur answer on my code (i post it now) .

Answer (score 0):

**Lost connection to device** is not a coding issue, your linked device got disconnected at that time due to data cable, If you will test this on emulator then you will not get this issue.
If you are saving user data on Shared preference then do encode your sensitive data before saving it.

Comment: I tried to test it on emulator but when i close the then for open it again i am not seeing my app on emulator, there is no app icon .

Comment: @Vishal_VE is correct. But if your app was loading on the emulator then the debug apk file would have been created in the build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/debug.apk of your project. Test your app on a physical device or first cold boot your emulator and then test your app. Hopefully it will work.